# Project Euler 3 - Highest Prime Factor

Tags: c++

before I start I want to clarify that I am **not** looking for code examples to get the answer; that would defeat the object of Project Euler.

The problem can be found here http://projecteuler.net/problem=3

I think I have a way of solving the problem, but the Algorithm is VERY slow; it has been running for nearly two and a half hours now. So I am looking for general advice on optimisation.

Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool primality(int);

int main(){
  long long lim =  600851475143;
  long long div = lim/2;
  bool run = true;

  while(run){
    if(lim%div==0 && primality(div)){
      cout << "HPF: " << div;
      run = false;
    }
    else{
      div--;
    }
    if(div<=1){
      break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

bool primality(int num){
  for(int i=2; i<num; i++){
    if(num%i==0 && i!=num){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Research the Sieve of Erosthanes.  You're looking at too many values.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I am just about to have a read.

Comment: Your prime function returns true for every odd number above 2.  And for every number 2 and below, it returns nothing.

Comment: For optimizing *this* code: in `primality` you can divide `num` by two to start with, just like you are in `main`.

Comment: primality only works on ints but you're passing long longs to it, this wont work

Comment: You can also calculate the list that `primality` makes one time, and just reuse that list.  `std::list<long>` is what I'd use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start `div` at 2 and count up instead of down, and divide it out from the number when the modulo is zero, you gain two big advantages that are useful here:

1. You don't have to check if `div` is prime, since it can't be composite because any prime factors smaller than it would already have been divided out.
2. You reduce the remaining problem size every time you find a factor, and, as it turns out, the input number has fairly small prime factors.

You could then also break once `div*div` is greater than the remaining number, as you know at that point that it must be a prime. This is because any divisors greater than the square root are "paired" with one less than the square root. However, since this is an "easy" problem, this optimization is not needed here (although it is useful for later problems).

Comment: Yep. If you implement the first paragraph, you should be able to bring the runtime down to less than a second.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on this now. Taking a bit of time though; quite tired.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Possible solution  but still its *time consuming* but answer can be guessed by the last option in console output 

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h> 
int prime(unsigned long long); 
using namespace std; 
int main(){ 
unsigned long long ii, ij; unsigned long long in; 
cin>>in; ij = ceil(in/2); 
if( (ij % 2) == 0 ) ij -= 1; 
for(ii = 3 ;ii < ij;ii+= 2){
if(in % ii == 0){
        if(prime(ii) == 1 ){
    cout<<" ans "<<ii<<endl;
    }
} 
} 
 return 0; 
} 
 int prime(unsigned long long ii){  
unsigned long long ij;
  for(ij = 3;ij < ii/2 ;ij += 2){ 
    if( (ii % ij) ==0){
       return 0;    
    }       
  }
  return 1; 
 }
```